# Ubuntu 22.04 randomly shuts down

Tags: shutdown

Ubuntu keeps shutting down randomly. I checked logs but I couldn't make anything out of it.

```
 -17:46:28 gdm-session-wor: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

-17:46:27 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.

-17:46:24 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file

-17:46:18 gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed

-17:46:18 kernel: iommu ivhd0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST device=00:00.0 pasid=0x00000 address=0xfffffffdf8000000 flags=0x0a00]

-17:46:18 bluetoothd: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)

-17:46:17 kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:800f11 TIME 1655934372 SOCKET 0 APIC 3 microcode 8001129

-17:46:17 kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0xdfb70000-0xdfb73fff]

-17:46:17 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
```

from the "important" tab of logs

Windows 10 Home

Comment: Ubuntu does not have a "random shutdown without logging anything" feature. Why would it? But your motherboard does. The two most common sources of random shutdowns are overheating and faulty power supply.

Comment: I'm dual booting and this does not happen with windows

Answer (score 1):

Here is my list of crash causers

1. GPU cause my system instability. My AMD Ryzen 1600 with AMD RX580 crashed by not with my Nvidia GTX-970. Eventually the kernel updates provided better drivers.
2. Nvidia driver and Nouveau driver. One would crash while in sleep mode, other would crash if I left a video playing when system went to sleep mode.
3. Try running Ubuntu 20.04 off a live USB and if it doesn't crash then its just an issue with Ubuntu 22.04 and once Ubuntu 22.04.1 gets released most issues like that will be fixed. That probably won't come out until August.
4. Post output of `inxi -Fx` that might give us details to help us better understand your system components.

My AMD FX-8350 ran overclocked on Kubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 for about 4 years. It rarely crashed and I never shut it off. My replacement Ryzen started rough on 20.04 but over the years got stable. Now my new Ryzen system Pop!_OS and Kubuntu 22.04 on the Ryzen 5600X and is a little unstable for GPU (Nvidia and AMD) issues but expect full stability from GPUs once 22.04.1 comes out.

Let us know what you figure out and what helped. Or post more details on your system.